# Multiple nodes can't communicate using one eNB

Tags: omnet++, veins, simulte

The simulation configuration I want is for the vehicle and the RSU to communicate with each other through `IEEE 802.11p` and `LTE` through one eNB(eNodeB).

Refer to the `veins_hetvnet` repository and the paper `Simulating cellular communications in vehicular networks: making SimuLTE interoperable with Veins` to configure the `.ned` of each node and write the source code.

The error seems to occur in the code below among `omnetpp.ini` codes.

```
# car
**.car[*].masterId = 1
**.car[*].macCellId = 1
# RSU
**.fRSU[*].masterId = 1
**.fRSU[*].macCellId = 1
# Cell (eNodeB)
**.Cell.macCellId = 1
**.Cell.macNodeId = 1

**.dynamicCellAssociation = true
```

When I run the simulation, the following error occurs.

> check_and_cast(): Cannot cast (LteMacEnbRealistic*)MyScenario.Cell.lteNic.mac to type 'LteMacEnbRealisticD2D*' -- in module (LteMacUeRealisticD2D) MyScenario.fRSU[0].lteNic.mac (id=184), during network initialization ..

The paper stated that it was the difference between automatic and manual coupling, but I don't know if that is true.

How can I modify the D2D communication with one eNB?

Comment: What would I need to do to see the same error on my computer?

Comment: @ChristophSommer The above problem seems to be solved. However, I wanted 4 fixed `UEs` to send messages to each other at the same time using `IEEE80211p`. However, even if a message is sent at the same time, it seems that each node cannot properly process the received message.

Comment: If this is a different question, please add an answer to this one and close it.